# Extract files with lftp and iterate over the extracted files

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, lftp

I am using `lftp` to extract some CSV data files from a FTP-server, with the following command:

```
lftp -e 'set ftp:use-mdtm false; set ftp:timezone Europe/Berlin; mirror --newer-than=now-1days --no-recursion --verbose -i "INERGIA.*\.csv" / /mnt/trailstone/itpf/DataInput; bye' -u [USERNAME],[PASSWORD] [SERVER-NAME]
```

This runs perfectly. However, after extracting the CSV files, I want to iterate over each of them in order to modify some of the data in the files with a Python script. Is there a way via `lftp` to get a hold of the extracted files directly by for instance assigning them to a variable?

At this moment I just do the following:

```
cd "/mnt/trailstone/itpf/DataInput/"

for f in $(find *.csv -ctime -1) do 
   python /mnt/trailstone/itpf/OnlineDataProcessing/OnlineExtraDataDownloader/changeDelimiter.py $f
done
```

But I would prefer getting a hold of the files directly through `lftp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing you want to do this because find might be hitting files with last status changed accidentally amongst previously fetched cvs files.

I'm not too familiar with lftp but I can think of a workaround:
have lftp download the files to a temporary location, do the python stuff and subsequently move the modified files to their final destination.
Alternatively extract the downloaded file list lftp's standard output (piped trough awk and grep, or whatever suits you best), populate a variable with that and then loop with that instead of $(find *.csv -ctime -1).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the case. I like the workaround, as this will ensure I am not unintentionally applying my script to other data files. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Not really-- but you can turn on lftp's download log which will track all the files downloaded.  Then parse that log for the file names and use it in your python script.

> xfer:log (boolean)  when true, lftp logs transfers to a file from xfer:log-file setting.
>
> xfer:log-file (path to file) the   file  to  log  transfers  to.
>   Default  is  ~/.local/share/lftp/transfer_log or             ~/.lftp/transfer_log.

Comment: Ok maybe lftp's output way is not usable but the other on will work.